# How to proof that $\Phi$ is contraction mapping using Banach fixed-point theorem?

Tags: calculus, analysis

$X=C \left [0,1/2  \right ] $ -  set of continuous function with distance
$\|f-g\|= \max_{x\in [0,1/2]}\left | f(x) - g(x)\right | $.
If
$$\Phi (f(x)) = 1 +\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt.$$
how can show that $\Phi$ is contraction mapping using Banach fixed-point theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $\Phi$ is contraction we do not need the Banach fixed-point theorem, but just the definition of [contraction map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping). Such theorem will be useful later to prove that $\Phi$ has a unique fixed point in $X$.

You should first show that $$x\to\Phi(f)(x)= 1 +\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$ is a continuous function when $f\in X=C \left [0,1/2  \right ]$, so that $\Phi:X\to X$.

Moreover, if $f,g\in X$,  for $x\in[0,1/2]$,  we have that
$$|\Phi (f(x))-\Phi (g(x))| =\left|\int_{0}^{x}(f(t)-g(t))dt\right|\\\leq
\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)-g(t))|dt\leq
\|f-g\|\int_{0}^{x}dt.$$
Can you take it from here and show that 
$$\|\Phi (f)-\Phi (g)\|\leq k \|f-g\|$$
for some $k\in [0,1)$?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Banach's fixed point theorem to prove that anything is a contraction. The theorems states that **if** a mapping is a contraction, **then** it has a unique fixed point.

You can prove that $\Phi$ is a contraction directly, i.e. you can look at $d(f, g)$ and $d(\Phi(f), \Phi(g))$ and compare the two.